# Como llamar a un evento desde un combo box que contiene un solo valor en Genexus 17

Tags: genexus, combobox

estoy desarrollando un formulario en un WebPanel de Genexus 17 U11 con WorkWithPlus que a medida que el usuario va llenando los primeros campos, va filtrando las opciones de los siguientes.
Para ello estoy usando Combo Box que contengan las opciones que que coincidan con los datos ya ingresados, pero al llegar a un Combo Box que contiene un solo valor, este no dispara el siguiente evento, ese seria: `&Cuentas.ControlValueChanged`, intente tambien con el evento `&Cuentas.Click` y tampoco se dispara.
Mi duda seria la siguiente: Como podria hacer que se dispare el siguiente evento cuando un Combo Box contiene un solo valor?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
Event &PerNumDoc.ControlValueChanged

    &Cuentas.Clear()
    &Codigo.Clear()
    
    prselCliente(&PerNumDoc.ToString().Trim(), &PerId, &CliId, &k) /*Procedimiento para obtener Identificadores*/
    
    For Each 
        Where OpeCliId  = &CliId
        
        &Cuentas.AddItem(&CtaId.ToString(), (Substr(OpeCtaContDes, 13, 2) + ' - ' + Substr(OpeCtaContDes, 15, 5))) /*&Cuentas es la variable en formato ComboBox en el Pattern*/
        
    When None
        msg('Sin Operaciones.')
    EndFor

EndEvent

Event &Cuentas.Click-ControlValueChanged /*Evento del siguiente Combo Box (que es el que no se dispara)*/

    For Each
        Where CtaId = &CtaId
    
        &Codigo.AddItem(ProdCod + ' - ', ProdNom)
        
    EndFor

EndEvent
```

Como mencione anteriormente, cuando el primer ComboBox contiene un solo valor, el siguiente evento no carga.

Desde ya, agradezco cualquier comentario! Saludos!

Comment: ¿Probaste con combos dinámicos condicionados? El tema del evento .ControlValueChanged es que sólo se ejecuta cuando el usuario lo cambia por pantalla, no cuando tu lo cambias por código, y el .Click te obligaría a ir al combo y elegir la única opción que tienes para que se ejecute. Lo que podrías hacer es en el evento &PerNumDoc.ControlValueChanged, agregar la lógica para que también cargue el combo de códigos. luego de haber cargado el de cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con lo siguiente, de esta forma cuando se carga el combo de cuentas, si queda con 1 solo item debería también cargarte el de códigos en el &PerNumDoc.ControlValueChanged:

```
Event &PerNumDoc.ControlValueChanged
    Do 'Carga combo cuentas'
    Do 'Carga combo códigos'
EndEvent

Event &Cuentas.Click-ControlValueChanged
    Do 'Carga combo códigos'
EndEvent

Sub 'Carga combo cuentas'
    &Cuentas.Clear()
    prselCliente(&PerNumDoc.ToString().Trim(), &PerId, &CliId, &k)
    
    For Each 
    Where OpeCliId  = &CliId
       &Cuentas.AddItem(&CtaId.ToString(), (Substr(OpeCtaContDes, 13, 2) + ' - ' + Substr(OpeCtaContDes, 15, 5))) 
    When None
       msg('Sin Operaciones.')
    EndFor
EndSub

Sub 'Carga combo códigos'
    &Codigo.Clear()
    For Each
    Where CtaId = &CtaId
        &Codigo.AddItem(ProdCod + ' - ', ProdNom)
    EndFor  
EndSub
```